# Product's Images' URLs are not same after migrating from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2

Tags: product-images, migration, magento2-migration-tool, media-images, data-migration

I have migrated **Magento 1.9** to **Magento 2.2.2** using **[magento-migration-tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/bk-migration-guide.html)** and after that, I have updated an image of the product which I have also update in Magento 1.9  but both images have different URL in front, Which are below.

> http://www.domain1.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/543x403/qwer751fc24f39b632cb88e6c5925d9b/p/r/pr_img01.jpg
>
> http://magento2.devdomain.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/23577479b544d65e11d54d23e4df6b67/p/r/pr_img01.jpg

These URLs are also different if we import new products also.

Is there any easy to map the images directory from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2

Thank you

Comment: It is default, After migration we copy media/catalog folder from magento 1 to pub/media/catalog and after content deploy all images are map automatically.

Comment: Yes, this is working fine. But, Is there any workaround so that we can have the same URLs of images as it will affect SEO.

Comment: No, I don't think so, Because folder structure also changed.

Comment: Okay. I have added an issue at [Product's Images' URLs are not same after migrating from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2 #597](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/597). Let's see if they have think about this or have any solution.